# Form Validation CI not work for all field

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

here is the **controller**

```
class Form extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $config = array(
           array(
                 'field'   => 'username',
                 'label'   => 'Username',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]|xss_clean'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'password',
                 'label'   => 'Password',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|matches[passconf]|md5'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'passconf',
                 'label'   => 'Password Confirmation',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required'
              ),   
           array(
                 'field'   => 'email',
                 'label'   => 'Email',
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]'
              )
        );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config); 

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
}
}
?>
```

and here is the views (myform.php , formsuccess.php)

**myform.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>
<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />
<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />
<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**formsuccess.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Your form was successfully submitted!</h3>
<p><?php echo anchor('form', 'Try it again!'); ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

after i run it, the validation works if the username not meet the requirements, but when username meet the requirements, the validation not work and go to success page, it should be work for all field on form, not just username. what should i do? sorry for my bad english

Comment: did you try `$this->form_validation->run() === FALSE` ?

Comment: not works lads :( any other advices?

Comment: Try removing is_unique[users.username] and is_unique[users.email], and see if it works.

Comment: I dont see any problem with CI validation. as @Andrew mentioned do you have username & email as feilds in user table ?

Answer (score 0):

formigniter.org/app

I prefer to use this, it automatically add validations.